# ¿ Como cambio la fuente del menú de navegación teniendo bootstrap y estilos propios?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Tengo mas problemas con la barra de navegacion. Me ayudaron @Camilo Vasquez, a reducir el tamaño de la fuente y de los botones.
Pero cambie a mayúsculas y aumente el texto de estas, y las celdas se vuelven a superponer.
Trato de cambiar el tamaño de la fuente en el selector ID #header pero no cambian, no se si tendrá que ver en algo bootstrap,
para poner una fuente mas pequeña pero a su vez bien legible, con las letras mas unidas.
Tampoco puedo reducir el tamaño del test-area de la busqueda.
En definitiva, ¿ Como puedo cambiar el estilo de las letras para que estén mas unidas ? ¿Y hay forma de reducir el test-area de busqueda ?
Gracias, no doy, hago pruebas y mas pruebas sin resultado.
Sigo mostrando el código que trabajo.

```css
/* LA VERDAD ES QUE FUNCIONA CASI TODO GRACIAS A LOS RETOQUES DE Camilo Vasquez, Alvaro Montoro*/
html, body {
    height:100%;
    margin:0px;
    color:#444444;
    -ms-text-size-adjust:100%;
    -webkit-text-size-adjust:100%;
    font:400 16px/1.8 sans-serif;
    }
    
    .nav-navbar-nav{
        font-size: 5;
    
    }
    .bgimg-1, .bgimg-2, .bgimg-3 {
    position:relative;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-attachment:fixed;
    background-position:center;
    background-size:cover;
    }
    .bgimg-1 {
    background-image:url("http://i64.tinypic.com/2jb5fs4.jpg");
    height:100%;
    }
    .bgimg-2 {
    background-image:url("http://i64.tinypic.com/2jb5fs4.jpg");
    height:100%;
    }
    .bgimg-3 {
    background-image:url("../imagenes/bg_03.jpg");
    height:100%;
    }
    .caption {
    position:absolute;
    left:10%;
    top:48%;
    width:80%;
    margin:auto;
    color:#FFFFFF;
    font-size:24px;
    text-align:center;
    letter-spacing:10px;
    background-color:#444444;
    }
    h2 {
    text-transform:uppercase;
    font:20px sans-serif;
    letter-spacing:4px;
    color:#444444;
    }
    a {
    text-decoration:none;
    letter-spacing:3px;
    }
    .navbar-nav{
      margin-left: 5% !important;
    }
    
    #header{
      position: fixed;
      width: 100%;
      z-index: 1000;
      font-size: 6
    }
    
    .navbar{
      margin-bottom: 0px !important;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">

<head>
    <title>PRINCIPAL</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="robots" content="noindex, nofollow">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">

    <!-- ESTOS ENLACES LES TENGO GRACIAS A Camilo Vasquez me sugirio para crear barra de navegacion-->
    
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link href="css/todo.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<!-- AQUI TAMBIEN FORMO PARTE Camilo Vasquez AYUDANDO ME CON LOS BOTONES DE LA BARRA DE NAVEGACION-->
<body>
    <header id="header">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse" role="navigation">
            <div class="container">
                <!-- Logo and responsive toggle -->
                <div class="navbar-header">

                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-fire"></span>
                      MIGUEL ESPESO
                    </a>
                </div>
                <!-- Navbar links -->
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                        <li class="active">
                            <a href="#">PRINCIPALES</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">CONTACTO</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">APLICACIONES</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="dropdown">
                            <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">SOBRE MI
                                <span class="caret"></span>
                            </a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                <li>
                                    <a target="_blank" href="estudios.html">CURRICULUM</a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    
                                    <a target="_blank" href="proyectos.html">LOGROS</a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="#">Diseño</a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    <!-- Search -->
                    <form class="navbar-form navbar-right" role="search">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control">
                        </div>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Buscar</button>
                    </form>

                </div>
                <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
            </div>
            <!-- /.container -->
        </nav>
    </header>
    <div class="bgimg-1">
        <div class="caption">
            <span>DALE AL SCROLL</span>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div style="color:#444444;background-color:#FFFFFF;text-align:center;padding:48px 80px;text-align:justify;">
        <h2 style="text-align:center;">CURRICULUM</h2>
        <h1>BIENVENIDOS A MI SITIO WEB...</h1>
        <p>Hola, me llamo Miguel y os voy a presentar mi sitio web, el cual estoy creando mientras realizo un curso de actívate. 
         En principio esta creado para mostrar mi perfil, experiencia laboral, formación académica y todos los conocimientos que 
         vaya adquiriendo en el curso. </p>
    </div>

    <div class="bgimg-2">
        <div class="caption">
            <span>100% HEIGHT</span>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div style="position:relative;">
        <div style="color:#FFFFFF;background-color:#444444;text-align:center;padding:48px 80px;text-align:justify;">
            <p>ESTO IRA MEJORANDOSE, SEGUN VAYA EXPERIMENTANDO</p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="bgimg-3">
        <div class="caption">
            <span>MAS IMAGENES</span>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div style="position:relative;">
        <div style="color:#444444;background-color:#FFFFFF;text-align:center;padding:48px 80px;text-align:justify;">
            <p>AQUI PONDRE IMAGENES, CUANDO VAYA APRENDIENDO</p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="bgimg-1">
        <div class="caption">
            <span>¡DIVERTIDO, EH!</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo único que te faltaba para que los estilos de tu cambio de tamaño de texto funcionaran era agregar la unidad de medida, tenias un `font-size: 7` pero te falto agregar la unidad de medida que ibas a usar para ese tamaño como por ejemplo `px`.

Ahora como recomendación te digo que es mejor agregar ese `font-size` directamente a la etiqueta `<a>` que es la que contiene el texto ya que al hacerlo en el `div#header` sería muy genérico y podría afectar otros textos que tuvieras dentro del `div`.

```css
/* LA VERDAD ES QUE FUNCIONA CASI TODO GRACIAS A LOS RETOQUES DE Camilo Vasquez, Alvaro Montoro*/
html, body {
    height:100%;
    margin:0px;
    color:#444444;
    -ms-text-size-adjust:100%;
    -webkit-text-size-adjust:100%;
    font:400 16px/1.8 sans-serif;
    }
    
    .nav-navbar-nav{
        font-size: 5;
    
    }
    .bgimg-1, .bgimg-2, .bgimg-3 {
    position:relative;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-attachment:fixed;
    background-position:center;
    background-size:cover;
    }
    .bgimg-1 {
    background-image:url("http://i64.tinypic.com/2jb5fs4.jpg");
    height:100%;
    }
    .bgimg-2 {
    background-image:url("http://i64.tinypic.com/2jb5fs4.jpg");
    height:100%;
    }
    .bgimg-3 {
    background-image:url("../imagenes/bg_03.jpg");
    height:100%;
    }
    .caption {
    position:absolute;
    left:10%;
    top:48%;
    width:80%;
    margin:auto;
    color:#FFFFFF;
    font-size:24px;
    text-align:center;
    letter-spacing:10px;
    background-color:#444444;
    }
    h2 {
    text-transform:uppercase;
    font:20px sans-serif;
    letter-spacing:4px;
    color:#444444;
    }
    a {
    text-decoration:none;
    letter-spacing:3px;
    }
    .navbar-nav{
      margin-left: 5% !important;
    }
    
    #header{
      position: fixed;
      width: 100%;
      z-index: 1000;
    }
    
    .navbar{
      margin-bottom: 0px !important;
    }
    
    .navbar ul li a{
      font-size: 12px
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">

<head>
    <title>PRINCIPAL</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="robots" content="noindex, nofollow">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">

    <!-- ESTOS ENLACES LES TENGO GRACIAS A Camilo Vasquez me sugirio para crear barra de navegacion-->
    
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link href="css/todo.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<!-- AQUI TAMBIEN FORMO PARTE Camilo Vasquez AYUDANDO ME CON LOS BOTONES DE LA BARRA DE NAVEGACION-->
<body>
    <header id="header">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse" role="navigation">
            <div class="container">
                <!-- Logo and responsive toggle -->
                <div class="navbar-header">

                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-fire"></span>
                      MIGUEL ESPESO
                    </a>
                </div>
                <!-- Navbar links -->
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                        <li class="active">
                            <a href="#">PRINCIPALES</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">CONTACTO</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">APLICACIONES</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="dropdown">
                            <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">SOBRE MI
                                <span class="caret"></span>
                            </a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                <li>
                                    <a target="_blank" href="estudios.html">CURRICULUM</a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    
                                    <a target="_blank" href="proyectos.html">LOGROS</a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="#">Diseño</a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    <!-- Search -->
                    <form class="navbar-form navbar-right" role="search">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control">
                        </div>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Buscar</button>
                    </form>

                </div>
                <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
            </div>
            <!-- /.container -->
        </nav>
    </header>
    <div class="bgimg-1">
        <div class="caption">
            <span>DALE AL SCROLL</span>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div style="color:#444444;background-color:#FFFFFF;text-align:center;padding:48px 80px;text-align:justify;">
        <h2 style="text-align:center;">CURRICULUM</h2>
        <h1>BIENVENIDOS A MI SITIO WEB...</h1>
        <p>Hola, me llamo Miguel y os voy a presentar mi sitio web, el cual estoy creando mientras realizo un curso de actívate. 
         En principio esta creado para mostrar mi perfil, experiencia laboral, formación académica y todos los conocimientos que 
         vaya adquiriendo en el curso. </p>
    </div>

    <div class="bgimg-2">
        <div class="caption">
            <span>100% HEIGHT</span>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div style="position:relative;">
        <div style="color:#FFFFFF;background-color:#444444;text-align:center;padding:48px 80px;text-align:justify;">
            <p>ESTO IRA MEJORANDOSE, SEGUN VAYA EXPERIMENTANDO</p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="bgimg-3">
        <div class="caption">
            <span>MAS IMAGENES</span>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div style="position:relative;">
        <div style="color:#444444;background-color:#FFFFFF;text-align:center;padding:48px 80px;text-align:justify;">
            <p>AQUI PONDRE IMAGENES, CUANDO VAYA APRENDIENDO</p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="bgimg-1">
        <div class="caption">
            <span>¡DIVERTIDO, EH!</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Vaya tela, y yo quiero ser programador, con cosas como estas no llegare muy lejos. Que fallo mas estupido, y las vueltas que me ha echo dar.                      Gracias compañero.                                                                                                      El estilo de la fuente se puede cambiar de algun modo, imagino que añadiendo al:  .navbar ul li a{
      font-size: 12px
    }                                                                                                                         Desde aqui podre cambiar. Gracias.

Comment: Claro puedes colocar el tamaño que desees, y tranquilo, de todos los errores se aprende te aseguro que este error no lo volverás a cometer en el futuro.

Comment: Ya me a pasado, una cosa, el estilo de la fuente se puede cambiar...??

Comment: Te refieres al tipo de letra? Claro ! Puedes usar la propiedad font-family en el mismo selector .navbar ul li a

Answer (score 3):

Necesitas añadir las unidades 'px', 'em' o '%'.

```
#header{
      position: fixed;
      width: 100%;
      z-index: 1000;
      font-size: 6px; ## Aquí olvidaste las unidades
    }
```

Comment: Ya me ha dicho el compañero @Camilo Vasquez, podia probar y probar con diferentes cantidades. Me interesaba saber si hay forma de cambiar el estilo de la fuente, no si sera posible...                                                                     Gracias